# Building turn-based game with Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am building a Python implementation of the turn-based game "Mancala" for a project at school. I already have a basic game with I/O from the console. Now I need to integrate graphics with Kivy into the project.
In short, the board of the game inherits Kivy's `GridLayout` and the pits are Kivy's `Button`s. A problem I run into is that to run the Kivy app, I need to call `app.run()`, and this method runs indefinitely. This is an issue because I have already implemented a base game without graphics with my own looper [here](https://github.com/katzuv/mancala-no-graphics/blob/master/game.py#L18), so if I run the Kivy app, the whole program just waits and practically stops.
My question is how do I integrate Kivy's loop (`app.run()`) with my own loop. I thought about calling all the game's logic from `on_press` of the pressed button, but that's a design I prefer not to pursue. Another solution I thought of was using two separate threads, one running Kivy's loop and another running my loop, but I do not have any of experience with threads.

The whole project can be found [here](https://github.com/katzuv/mancala-no-graphics) (yes, I know the repo's name is now incorrect :-)).
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way is if you use the Clock class in Kivy to run you Game._turn() method at regular intervals.

```
from kivy.clock import Clock
```

And:
    Clock.schedule_interval(Game._turn, 0.1)